# Method in abstract class returning an instance of the class that implements it

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

Is it possible in an abstract class to have a method that 'generically' returns an instance of the class that extends it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to provide a bit of extra information, and to answer your question in the comments. Kayaman's answer is exactly what I would have suggested as well, given the information in your question.

However, as you implied with your comment-question, this method will only invoke the default constructor. In order to invoke one of the parameterized constructors, you need to effectively "locate" it by its signature using the [`getDeclaredConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor) method.

Like so (borrowing from Kayaman's answer):

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public AbstractClass getInstance(Object[] parameters, Class<?>...parameterTypes) {
        return getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(parameterTypes).newInstance(parameters);
    }
}
```

Making sure of course that the order of elements in `parameters` and `parameterTypes` corresponds to the constructor's signature.

Answer (score 3):

You could instantiate the class in the following way, but maybe you should tell us what you're trying to achieve. Another simpler way would probably be to implement `Clonable`.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public AbstractClass getInstance() {
        return getClass().newInstance();
    }
}
```

or in the case of a constructor accepting parameters:

```
return getClass().getDeclaredConstructors(String.class, Integer.class).newInstance(someString someInteger);
```

Comment: What about if the abstract class has a constructor which takes arguments. Can I pass them with the above since an implementing class will definitely do super(arg1,arg2)